# How do I pass a pointer to unmanaged memory (an IntPtr) to an Alea CUDA kernel?

Tags: c#, aleagpu

I have an `IntPtr hData` that points to the beginning of an array of data that is stored in unmanaged memory.  When I try to pass it using the CUDA kernel described below, I get a `System.Exception: i64 is not a struct type`.  How should I be passing in a pointer to an array in unmanaged memory using an Alea CUDA kernel?

```
unsafe private static void CopyDataToDeviceMemory(
    IntPtr hData,
    deviceptr<float> dData,
    int dataLength)
{
    int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

    for (int i = start; i < dataLength; i += stride)
    {
        dData[i] = DeviceFunction.Convert<ushort, float>(
            *((ushort*)(hData + i * 2)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question completely but maybe you're trying to use the IntPtr as a value instead of a pointer.  Try marshaling the value back and using that like: var hDataValue = Marshal.ReadInt64(hData); and then using the hDataValue.

Comment: I do see you're using ushort* and converting it to * for pointer but wouldn't hData + 1 * 2 be doing work on a pointer and not the value?  If I'm wrong I apologize; it's late here.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I am trying to do pointer arithmetic.  So `hData` points to the beginning of the array, then `hData + 1` should point to the next byte, and so on.  I am trying to basically copy the array that `hData` points to into `dData`.

Comment: gotcha, I see that now.  :/

Comment: Where does hData locate? I guess it is on host, right? if so, you cannot directly use it in a kernel. You must first transfer the hData into device, using functions such as `Alea.CUDAInterop.cuMemcpyHtoD`.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you @XiangZhang.  However, does this mean I can't get CUDA to do a `short` to `float` copy?  I read somewhere that you can do it with textures...

Comment: @XiangZhang thanks for sharing about `Alea.CUDAInterop`, however, I was unable to find `cuMemcpyHtoD` in the 3.0.2 documentation?  Is there any way to do this using the C# library?

Comment: @ArKi Alea.CUDAInterop is just a P/Invoke interface for CUDA Driver API (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM), and since you are using unmanaged data, so there is no wrapping on them yet. The doc of this P/Invoke interface is actually the NVIDIA documentation. I try to create you an example these days when I found some time.